# how to print the data only once when the data is same

Tags: perl, loops

when I use the below code iam printing the days for all the tech.

```
while( my ( $A1, $Days, $package, $Tech)= $TF_QUERY->fetchrow_array())
{
  print "$file $A1,$Days,$package,$tech";
}

A1    Days  package     Tech

001    10   value1      2g

001    10    value1     3g

001    10    value1     wifi

001    10    value1     NA
```

I want to print the output in the following format,Can you please help me out to print the below format.

```
A1    Days  package     Tech

001    10     value1        2g

001          value1     3g

001          value1     wifi

001          value1     NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a short term memory by remembering and replacing the previous values once they change. (check the perl code, might have some mistakes since it is untested, the concept however is solid):

```
$prevPackage="";
$prevA1=-1;
$prevDays=-1;
$prevTech="";
$prevFile="";
while( my ( $A1, $Days, $package, $Tech)= $TF_QUERY->fetchrow_array())
{
  if($prevFile!=$file) {
    print "$file";
    $prevFile=$file;
  }
  if($prevDays!=$Days) {
    etc etc etc
  }
}
```